# Changing UITableView style as "Grouped" Causes Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, xcode9

Changing UITableView style from Interface Builder (.xib file not storyboard) causes a crash on
xCode 9. I think its an apple bug. But Is there anyone that found a solution ?

[image]

Comment: what the crash report

Comment: xcode is hanging and crashing.

Comment: That is a Xcode 9 bug. You should report Apple from https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: any workaround on this issue?

Comment: same Issue here

Comment: Not yet. waiting for an update :(

Comment: You can open the xib file as source code and change the value from plain to grouped via text. This way you can at least use the xib at runtime. You won't be able to edit the xib file while it's in grouped mode though. I would suggest finish editing your xib file using interface builder, then change it to grouped via editing the xml whenever your UI is stable, and you need to test.

Comment: I already tried it before. it didnt work.

Comment: @Nailer worked for me. 

Comment: @AhmadFarrag good to hear but it crashes on my xcode if i changed in source code then try to show in Interface Builder :/

Comment: @MehmetAKYOL Yes, It's really annoying, My workaround is to change this to plain to be able to view the Interface Builder.

Comment: Still crashing in Xcode 9.0.1 :(

Comment: this is so bad!!!

Comment: NOTE: This only occurs in .xib files, not in storyboards.

Comment: I was think this is my issue cause it just happened in my new project, but my old projects is still able to change to grouped style (those also use .xib files). After I saw his question, I think it’s a bug of compatibility of Swift&Xcode9. Anyone can tell you’re using Swift or Objective-C when you crash?

Comment: My project is written with Objective C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in Xcode 9.1. 
[image: Release not Xcode9.1]

Refer this [release note](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html) for detail.

You can download DMG/XIP file from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33773819/1753005).

Answer (score 2):

Open your xib file via editing the xml and replace: style="plain" =>  dataMode="prototypes" style="grouped"

Comment: dataMode is Storyboard spesific property. Did you try it on xib ? :) i will try later and i will inform about result.